# How I can set update=false on specific filed of a document in SpringData mongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have a document/entity with following fields: '*dtmCreated*' and '*dtmModified*'. Now what I want is the value for *dtmCreated* should saved on insertion, this field should not be updating while updating an entity.